# Determination of Ageing by ECG inclusions/exclusions?

Tags: biochemistry, physiology, cardiology, senescence, imaging

I am studying ageing and considering ECG signal because of its high sensitivity in theory (escardio). Some factors

- Sensitivity
- Gender
- Medical treatment
- ...

**Benchmark**: 
RTG dental + wrist uncertainty $\pm$2 years. Etc tooth washing, and hardness of drinking water affect much the dental health. Exposure to the ionisative radiation is problematic so less radiative approach would be nice.

### ECG

Cardiac characteristics by ECG signal in power spectrum, having greater uncertainty than RTG dental 2016 because no sufficient exclusions/inclusions and too much exclusions covering data segments of autonomic nervous systems. 
Processes to be excluded from the ECG signal

- respiratory process
- heart beat itself
- some cellular-tissue processes

Some cellular-tissue processes

- ROS determination ...
- some genes about lipids and their characteristics with ageing in metabolic syndrome
- decreased replication of cellular ageing
- [DNA replication stress, genome instability and aging](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2190710/pdf/gkm1059.pdf)
- [MICCAI 2012 Workshop on Novel Imaging Biomarkers for Alzheimer's Disease and Related Disorders](http://picsl.upenn.edu/docs/nibad12_proceedings_reduced_20120905.pdf)

Low-Cost Targets

- internal physiology of cardiac events in association with ...
- cardiac and brain imaging makers related to substance use disorder, HIV, and aging (Stanford)

---

How can you determine aging by biochemical test and imaging?

Comment: I think you need to focus the question a little more. As it stands you list methods to study aging and then summarily ask how to study aging. Perhaps pick a specific technique and ask a specific question about your problems with that specific technique for better reception. I think going down a list of techniques and giving them each a thorough exposition warrants an answer that is too broad.

Comment: @Kendall Yes, you are right. I put the focus on Cardiology but including inclusions and exclusions. ECG signal has the great potential in high sensitivity. (escardio)